# Thread.Sleep() sleeps for longer

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Winform which needs to wait for about 3 - 4 hours. I can't close and somehow reopen the App, as it does few things in background, while it waits.

To achieve the wait - without causing trouble to the UI thread and for other reasons -, I have a BackgroundWorker to which I send how many milliseconds to wait and Call `Thread.Sleep(waitTime);` in its doWork event. In the `backGroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` event, I do what the program is supposed to do after the wait.

This works fine on the development machine. i.e. the wait ends when it has to end. But on the Test machine, it keeps waiting for longer. It happened two times, first time it waited exactly 1 hour more than specified time and second time it waited more for about 2 Hours and 40 minutes.

Could there be any obvious reason for this to happen or am I missing something?

The dev machine is Win XP and Test machine is Win 7.

Comment: Why don't you use the Timer control instead of a thread.sleep within a background worker ?

Comment: WHy would the accuracy of a timer be any better than sleep()?  AFAIK, the timer intervals are implemented by timed waits on the Windows Message Queue upon which the thread must be waiting, so, same as sleep().  Using a timer inplies that the calling thread must be running a message-queue - often, this is undesirable.  Try waiting for an hour deep inside some comms stack without using sleep() - painful and error-prone state-machine required.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks. Can you please tell me what a comms stack is! ?
I tried using a Timer. Again works good on my machine, but haven't yet tried on the other machine. (The two machines are at a 12 hr difference time zones). I will post my findings here, when I get to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx) which explains the reason:

> Thread.Sleep(n) means block the current thread for at least the number
>   of timeslices (or thread quantums) that can occur within n
>   milliseconds.  The length of a timeslice is different on different
>   versions/types of Windows and different processors and generally
>   ranges from 15 to 30 milliseconds.  This means the thread is almost
>   guaranteed to block for more than n milliseconds.  The likelihood that
>   your thread will re-awaken exactly after n milliseconds is about as
>   impossible as impossible can be.  So, Thread.Sleep is pointless for
>   timing.

By the way it also explains why not to use Thread.Sleep ;)

I agree to the other recommendations to use a Timer instead of the Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Your cite explains why it's not a good idea to use Thread.Sleep for accurate timing, but in my opinion it does not explain why Thread.Sleep waits 5 hours instead of 4 hours.

Comment: @Werner Henze: I think it does explain it. As Thread.Sleep uses several timeslices depending on your machine which all aren't exact the sum of differences could cause the problem. The difference of over one hour can especially be caused when the timeslices are shared with other threads running on the machine.

Comment: Interesting. I knew that Thread.Sleep wasn't really accurate, but still; even if Thread.Sleep will divide the given n into slices of 15 to 30 milliseconds; how does that make 4 hours into 5? I could see that it would turn up to be 4 hours and 30 milliseconds, or just below 4 hours (those are timing issues); but not a whole one hour more. Doesn't it maintain a total slept millisecond count?

Comment: I would have guesses that it splits the 4 hours into e.g. 480000 timeslices of 30ms. If then some of them aren't accurate the sum of the differences could cause the big difference.

Comment: IME, long sleeps are reasonable accurate unless the machine is grossly overloaded.  I have no idea what's going on with the OP, but it should not be sleep() inaccuracy over that period.

Comment: Just in case things have changed, recently, I just tried sleep(1000*60*5) on my Vista box.  Started the sleep at 17:58:00 by my analogue wall clock. After making a coffee, I was back in my office to see the sleep fire at 18:03:00 with sufficient accuracy that I did not notice any discrepancy.  Obviously, there was some, but not human-detectable over 5 min.

Comment: Thanks All. Well, the issue was something very basic. Since (I) was testing a hours-long wait, the test machine went to stand-by mode after some x minutes of idleness. Hence Thread.Sleep and Timer were randomly off from my expected wait! Now it fine as per my precision requirements..

Answer (score 3):

I propose to use ManualResetEvent instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
mre.WaitOne(waitTime);

...
//your background worker process
mre.Set();
```

As a bonus you will have an ability to interrupt this sleep quicker.

Comment: Again, works on same mechanism as sleep().  Same issues.  Timers are the same - fired by OS waits on the Windows Message Queue timing out.  All these timers/sleeps/waits use the same OS functionality.  5 hours instead of 4 hours is just.. weird.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, the difference in wait time cannot solely be explained by the information that you have given us. I would really think that the cause of the difference lies within the moment of starting the sleep. So the actual `Thread.sleep(waitTime);` call. Are you sure that the sleep is called at the moment you think it is?

And, as suggested by the comment, if you really need to wait for this long; consider using a `Timer` to start the events needed. Or even scheduling of some sort, within your application. Of course, this depends on your actual implementation and thus can be easier said than done. But it 'feels' silly, letting a BackgroundWorker sleep for so long.

Comment: I am sure that the sleep is called at the time moment I think it is. But seeing the answers and the link about Thread.Sleep(), I am thinking of using a Timer, for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**PREFIX: This requires .NET 4 or newer**

Consider making your function async and simply doing:

```
await Task.Delay(waitTime);
```

Alternately, if you can't make your function async (or don't want to) you could also do:

```
Task.Delay(waitTime).Wait();
```

This is a one-line solution and anyone with a copy of Reflector can verify that Task.Delay uses a timer internally.